# Architecture for a self-running Python script on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, automation

I have the following set-up

1. A Python script
2. A Mac OSX Automator application with said script
3. An iCal alert that runs the Automator (and thus the Python script) on a regular schedule

All of the above works just fine. But I need to make a change. I need the script to check a web site for a time in the future (that same day) and then come back prior to that time and run itself again. I know how to do the first part (get the time) but I have no clue how to do the second part. How do you get a Python script to (1) run itself at a regular time and then (2) run again at some point in the future? The point in the future will change on a regular basis. Sometimes it would be as early as 10AM, other times it may be 7PM.

Any thoughts on this and pseudo-code are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to hard-code anything in - use [`crontab`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/crontab.1.html) to schedule when your script first runs. It checks the website for the time it's supposed to run again, then you call [`time.sleep()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) until the task needs to run again.

Comment: Doesn't this add a lot of overhead to the processing? It basically means that my script will be held in sleep for multiple hours at a time. I'm coming from a Windows background where this might not be the best idea, is Mac OS better at managing sleep like this?

Comment: @JimBeam - sleep in a Unix perspective means just what it says - the process is sleeping, and utilizing essentially zero resources. The OS receives the sleep call, and then wakes the process up again once the specified time has passed. Contrast this with the other answer, where the process is continually running until something changes.

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable to the future time, and check it in a while() loop